# rails redirect_to problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, routes

I am developing a rails app and have a question.

In my routes.rb:

`map.connect 'admin', :controller => "/admin/users", :action => "index"`

So when I go to "http://mydomain.com/admin", it redirects to "http://mydomain.com/admin/users/index".
However, the address remains as "http://mydomain.com/admin".
Thus, links in the page are wrong because they are created based on "http://mydomain.com/admin".

What's the solution to this problem?

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not redirecting the browser it's just setting up /admin and /admin/users to trigger the same action.

You could try:

```
map.connect 'admin', :controller => "/admin/users", :action => "redirect_to_index"
```

Then in your controller write:

```
def redirect_to_index
  redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

This will send a redirect to the browser, causing it to display the correct URL.

Hopefully there is a better method that only involves routes.rb. This site might be helpful -> [redirect-routing-plugin-for-rails](http://pinds.com/2006/07/18/release-redirect-routing-plugin-for-rails/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

map.connect 'admin/:action/:id', :controller => 'admin/users'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any same-domain links on the page start with a /, and use the full path.  Generally you should use Rails route methods to generate your links when possible.  Same goes for using the `image_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag` helpers.

So if you have a link to "privacy.html", change it to "/privacy.html" and you should be all good no matter where in the route structure you are.  This is extra nice when you start extracting your view code out to re-usable partials.

Answer (score 0):

Use link_to and button_to (in [UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html))